# can not download visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

i format my computer and try install visual studio.
but run to installer file, but not start to filedownload like this picture.

after a while, appear message.
Unable to download installation files, check your internet connection and try again.

Comment: Hi, it did not happend to me, you tried opening as admin?

Comment: of course. and windows update is recently version too.

Comment: And this is the latest installer too?

Comment: yes. i downloaded this file from official homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with your internet connection and firewall settings.
I formatted and reset my pc and it came back to normal.